# Search results with custom loop don't update when paged

Tags: search, loop, customization, pagination

I have the following code in my search results page to split up posts per category.

When I go to the 2nd page of pagination, the results are exactly the same as the first.

I'm assuming $paged has to be inserted but i'm not sure where.

Any help would be appreciated

Code: http://wordpress.pastebin.com/qWnaLxgd

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate for the many similar questions already asked regarding loops and pagination, please see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+loop+pagination

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination not working with custom loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 51:

```
query_posts("s='$s'&cat=177");
```

change to this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts("s='$s'&cat=177&paged=$paged");
```