# the-events-calendar, pagination with tribe_get_events()

Tags: navigation, get-posts, the-events-calendar

i'm using [the events calendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-events-calendar/) plugin and at some place i use the [tribe_get_events()](http://tri.be/support/documentation/the-events-calendar-template-tags-general-functions/#functiontribe_get_events) function to show the upcoming events. Point is, i need to create a pagination for those results.

The `tribe_get_events` function is using wordpress' `get_posts()` and accepts some parameters like `posts_per_page`. I've tried adding some pagination parameters as i would with a `WP_Query()` request but without any success yet.

Here goes the code:

```
<?php global $post; 
$all_events = tribe_get_events(array( 'eventDisplay'=>'upcoming', 'posts_per_page'=> 3, ));
foreach($all_events as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php } wp_pagenavi();  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') does change anything. Am also using the [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) plugin but if there's a way to get the navigation working here without it it'd be already fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination not working with custom loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Set the offset manually.

```
$offset = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : my_parse_url_for_offset();

function my_parse_url_for_offset() {
    if( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/page/' ) !== false ) {
        $url = explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        $url_c = count( $url );

        for( $i = 0; $i < $url_c; $i++ ) {
            if( $url[$i] == 'page' ) {
                if( is_numeric( $url[$i+1] ) )
                    $page = $url[$i+1];
            }
        }
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }
    return $page;
}
```

then feed it as an arg in `get_posts()`