# Pagination for a category

Tags: categories, pagination

Hi I have page displaying 20 featured images and info of a specific category, I wish to able to have pagination so I can have multiple pages for the category.

How do I do this? I cant seem to get it work.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="modus-grid">
     <?php query_posts(array('category__in' => array(5), 'posts_per_page' => 20)); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php $currentid = get_the_id(); ?>

                    <div class="grid-box grid-block mod-box width33">

                        <div class="view view-first">                                
                                <?php if (get_the_post_thumbnail($currentid, array(167, 167)) != "") { ?>

                                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($currentid, array(300,600)); ?></a>
                                <?php } else { ?> 
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /><img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/default.png' alt='Default'/></a>
                                <?php } ?>

                            <div class="mask">  
                                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($currentid); ?></a></h2>
                                <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt( $post->parent ); ?></p>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="info">Read More...</a>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 

                    <?php
                endwhile;
            endif;

            wp_reset_query();
            ?> 
            <div class="clearfix">
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What **template file** is this, and **[why are you using `query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination not working with custom loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)

Comment: I created a custom page template for the yootheme master theme. I used query_posts because that's the only way I know how to do it. My php is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

The problem exists because you are using `query_posts()`, instead of properly filtering the main query via `pre_get_posts`.

Remove your `query_posts()` call from the template file, then add the following to functions.php:

```
function wpse74325_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_category( 5 ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '20' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse74325_pre_get_posts' );
```

This function will properly modify the main query object, *before* retrieving posts, allowing WordPress to assign pagination properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any pagination parameters. Like this, [from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)...

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( 'paged=' . $paged );
```

Notice that code uses `WP_Query` not `query_posts`. Don't use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). It is pretty much never the best choice for creating a loop.

The top of your Loop should look like...

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$my_query = new WP_Query(array('category__in' => array(5), 'posts_per_page' => 20,'paged'=>$paged)); ?>
    <?php if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) :
         the_post(); ?>
```

And then the rest of your loop.

You probably also want [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) and [`previous_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_posts_link).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for help, when I tried the code it created a never ending page I obviously did it wrong.

Comment: Here is the code < http://i160.photobucket.com/albums/t195/rt840/tedwdws.jpg >

Comment: There is no need to use a custom query when the main query is the one intended to be modified. Let the template system do its job. :)

Comment: @ChipBennett : It isn't clear that this is a category archive page, and given that the category is hard-coded-- `array(5)`-- I am guessing that it is not, which conclusion is supported by the first sentence of the question.

Comment: Ah, well if it's the case that it's a custom page template, the solution is covered [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-query-loops).