# Why won't my paged wp_query work?

Tags: wp-query, pagination, paged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pagination not working with custom loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)

Any ideas why this paged `wp_query` doesn't seem to want to work?

I've tried replacing the `pt_pagination` function with the default next/prev posts links and that didn't work either...

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'pt-portfolio',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$pt_portfolio_loop = new WP_Query($args);
while($pt_portfolio_loop->have_posts()) : $pt_portfolio_loop->the_post();
?>

<?php
$cols = of_get_option('pt_portfolio_layout');
get_template_part('portfolio', $cols);
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php pt_pagination(); ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on _doesn't seem to want to work_. What do you expect to happen? What does or doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `pt_pagination` position

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>

<?php pt_pagination(); ?>
```

Or you can try Pippin code https://github.com/pippinsplugins/EDD-Starter-Theme/blob/master/front-page.php#L5-L14

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: I imagine the `wp_reset_postdata();` breaking the pagination :)

Comment: Nope, that didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any custom query before you do the 'pages' stuff? If so, try to add wp_reset_query(); or wp_reset_postdata(); before this get_query_var('paged'); code.