# Pagination for custom post type not working

Tags: pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pagination not working with custom loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)

So I have a post type called portfolio, but I can't get it to paginate.
I'd also like it to paginate on single pages so each item has a prev/next link at the bottom, but this won't work either.

I try adding this on the single page and the links just don't appear.

I've been banging my head against a brick wall for days now trying to find a solution for this and nowhere online can I find one.

```
<div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('Older Posts') ?></div>
            <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts') ?></div>




<?php
                                 $portfolio_query = new WP_Query(array(
                                'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                                'showposts' => -1
                                ) );
                           ?>


                           <?php while ($portfolio_query->have_posts()) : $portfolio_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>

                         <div class="portthumbwrap">

                         <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <div class="portmetacontainer">
                                <div class="link-text">
                                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                                    <ul>
                                     <?php
                                        $posttags = get_the_tags();
                                        if ($posttags) {
                                          foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                                            echo '<li>' .$tag->name. '</li>'; 
                                          }
                                        }
                                        ?>

                                    </ul>   

                                </div> <!-- end div link-text -->

                            </div> <!-- end div postmetacontainer -->
                         </a>

                           <div class="figure">

                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                           </div>


                         </div> <!-- end div portthumbwrap -->











                           <div class="clearfix"></div>
                           <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: why do you create a new query for your portfolio items? what template are you using this in? what happens if you just run the default loop? for single views you want `next_post_link`, note that it's singular post, not plural posts.

Comment: It says 'posts' here. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link

Why not create a new query for the portfolio posts? I'm not being sarcastic or anything, I really don't know, the WP codex seems geared towards people that are experts in php. 
And the template is one I made.

Comment: Please [**search for related questions**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+loop+pagination) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if posts_per_page is set to -1 you're showing all posts without pagination. Try setting it to 5 for example.

Comment: Also see this reference about setting up pagination http://wp-snippets.com/pagination-without-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your custom query is that you pass no pagination parameters, and it has no relationship to the default query variables that pagination functions operate with.

When you [register your portfolio post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), set `has_archive` to `true` and `rewrite` `slug` to the URL you want your portfolio items to appear at:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio' )
```

then use the default loop in your template:

```
while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();
    the_title();
    // etc...
endwhile;
```

and the pagination functions will just work without you having to do anything else.

If you want to customize the template from other post archives, name your template `archive-portfolio.php` where `portfolio` is the name you've registered your post type as. See the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for more info.

[`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) (plural) is for an archive page, [`next_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) (singular) is the next single post after the current single post being viewed.

Comment: I just changed next_posts_link to post (singular) and added 'archive' to the 'supports' array.

Now it paginates just fine on the single page.

Is that 'right' in technical sense?