# Custom post type navigation - 404 on page 2

Tags: custom-post-types, navigation

I have a custom post type `portfolio` and now I'm trying to enable navigation for the template where 10 portfolio items are shown. I'm using the following code to query the posts:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) 
    { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) 
    { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else 
    { $paged = 1; }
$posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');

$offset = ( $posts_per_page * $paged ) - $posts_per_page;

query_posts(array('paged'=>$paged, 'posts_per_page'=> $posts_per_page, 'post_type'=>'portfolio', 'offset' => $offset));
```

The current link structure is as follows:

```
domain.com/portfolio //main portfolio page, showing 10 portfolio items
domain.com/portfolio/item //shows a single portfolio item
domain.com/portfolio/page/2 //should show the next set portfolio items, but shows a 404 error instead.
```

I'm assuming the problem is that when you visit `domain.com/portfolio/page/2` that WordPress assumes that `page` is a portfolio item, so it looks for that specific portfolio item rather than showing the next portfolio page.

How could I solve this issue? I'd rather not change the link structure for easier browsing.

I do not want to use a plugin like `WP Page Navi`, so this is not a duplicate with [Pagination not working with custom loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the page is named is the same as the `custom post type`, this is not possible in WordPress unfortunately.

You could solve this issue by changing the page its `slug`.