# WordPress site with custom theme, can't get pagination to update posts on page 2+

Tags: loop, pagination

I have inherited a WordPress site which has a custom theme which I have in the main been able to modify to suit the clients needs.

I am having trouble, however, with the pagination of the 'category-blog.php' page I have created.

The pagination seems to be working in that blog/page/2/ is added to the URL (I have added some debugging code which proves the pagination works), but the posts (which are set to view 10 at a time) never update and the page only ever shows the most recent 10 posts no matter what page you navigate to.

```
<?php
/** Template Name: blog **/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="content_container">
<div id="left_container">
<div id="product-container"><!-- begin product container -->

<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts( 'cat=1' ); ?>

<h1 class="blog">Blog Posts</h1>

<!-- Start the Loop. -->

<!-- debugging -->
<?php if ( $paged < 2 ) : ?>
<p>Text for first page of Blog Listing. Used for debugging. Will be removed.</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Text for subsequent pages of Blog Listing. Used for debugging. Will be removed.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- end debugging -->

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="entry">

<!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
<div class="meta-info"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?>        </div>

<!-- Display the Post's content in a div box. -->
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<hr />
</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (show_posts_nav()) : ?>
<div class='navigation'>
    <span class='older'><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries'); ?></span>
    <span class='newer' style="float: right; padding-right: 24px;"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;'); ?></span>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- end product container -->

</div><!--right build container-->

<?php get_sidebar(3); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any help with getting the above code to work would be much appreciated. Been banging my head on the desk for hours with this one.

Craig

Comment: Did you read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)?

Comment: Never use query_posts, use `WP_Query` or `pre_get_posts` instead. Also, do you not think it strange that you ask which page you're on, then do a query, but you never tell the query the page number?

Comment: Thanks guys. Much appreciated. I now have it working properly. Thanks for the pointers.