# WP Paginate not working properly

Tags: wp-query, pagination

Im creating a WP for a custom type post in a page template:

```
    <?

                global $paged;
                global $notquery;
                $temp = $notquery; 
                $notquery = null; 


                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'noticias',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'posts_per_page' => 1

                );

                $notquery = new WP_Query($args); 

                while ( $notquery->have_posts() ) :
                    $notquery->the_post();
                    global $post;
                    ?>
```

And it just dont works properly. I can access page 2 with /page/2/. So, paged seems to work. It prints out the wp-paginate navigation div, but nothing inside it.

```
   <div class="navigation"></div>
```

Whats the problem guys? thanks!

Comment: What function or method are you using for the navigation links?  Why are you setting $notquery to null?  You also need to be using wp_reset_postdata()

Comment: Found the problem. It worked pretty well with query_posts(). Thanks!

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop for a proper solution.

Answer (score -1):

It worked with query_posts(). Thanks!