# Classic Custom Post Types and WP-PageNavi

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

Has anyone made this work?
I am searching for a solution for 2 days now, and it won`t work.
I have...

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$updates = new WP_Query(array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged, 'post_type' => array('review', 'news') ));
```

Then i begin the loop...

```
 while ( $updates->have_posts() ) : $updates->the_post()
```

bla bla bla

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <nav class="pagination">
        <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $updates ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query();?>
    </nav>
```

The thing is that pagination works (just because I don`t have a 404 page). The title is Page Not found - but the pagination works as it should.
If i add the 404 page, I would just get the error.
My website is http://fantappstick.com - just in case you want to see this.

I don`t know what else to do...

Comment: Did you read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)?

Comment: It`s now live on my website. No change.