# Pagination paginate_links() Not Working

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

Here's my code

```
<?php

                        query_posts(array('category_name'=>'nutrition','posts_per_page'=>'3','paged' => get_query_var('paged')));
                        while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
                        <div class="nutrition-post-item clearfix">
                            <div class="alignleft">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  
                                the_post_thumbnail(  array(90,90,)); } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="alignright">
                            <a class="semibold title" href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
                            <p class="author">Posted By: <span class="bold"><?php the_author(); ?></span></p>
                            <?php the_excerpt();?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query( );?>
                        <?php echo paginate_links( $args ) ?>
<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

The problem is, its not even working, What's wrong with my code? [Here's the page](http://seemynewwebsite.com/g2bm/fuel/)

Comment: Please search for related posts. The issue is with the use of `query_posts()`, and this question has been asked and answered several times.

Comment: ^ How has `wp_pagenavi` in the [linked answered question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop) got anything to do with this problem? I can't see how that other question provides any insight for this particular issue.