# Pagination linking to first page

Tags: query-posts, pagination

I have created a query which work correctly and displays the pagination correctly. However when clicking the links /products/category/application-range/page/2 the page will load and go back to /products/category/application-range/ rather than page 2, is there any reason why?

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'connected_type'      => 'product_to_category',
  'connected_items'     => $post,
  'posts_per_page'  => 10,
  'paged'           => $paged,
  'post_parent'     => 0,
  'orderby'         => 'menu_order',
  'order'           => 'ASC'
);

$products = query_posts($args);
```

Comment: Probably [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can take a look at [this question and the answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) and check if you really want to use `query_posts()` as it is not recommended while dealing with posts pagination. Why not use [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) action instead? Or you can try something like this:

```
<?php

    $custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'connected_type' => 'product_to_category',
        'connected_items' => $post,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'order_by' => 'menu-order',
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
    ));

?>
```