# WordPress custom post type category pagination 404 Error

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, 404-error

This problem is giving me a headache and I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix it.

I have a custom post type called Review. Here is how it is defined:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array( 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'review'), 
                    'public' => true, 
                    'has_archive' => true, 
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'label' => 'Review', 
                    'publicly_queryable' => true,
                    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'), 
                    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'author')
                  );
    register_post_type( 'review', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

My archive page, handled by archive-review.php, works fine for pages like this

```
http://www.acme.com/review/page/3/
```

However, when categories are involved, wordpress does not display the "next" page. Instead, it goes to a 404. For example, when I try to access this:

```
http://www.acme.com/category/random/page/2/
```

Why does that give a 404? Also, it no longer is powered by archive-review.php, but archive.php (which makes sense I guess)

archive.php query stuff:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
        $catID = $cat->term_id;
        $args = (array('post_type' => array('post', 'review'), 'cat' => $catID, 'paged' => $paged));
        query_posts($args);
```

Please help!! I am very frustrated!

Comment: `http://www.acme.com/category/random/page/2/` is random a typo?

Comment: Have you seen http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts?

Comment: @vancoder random is the category slug in this example

Comment: @toscho I will try it with creating a new wp_query as the example i've seen on CSS Tricks, but I'm not sure why that would make a difference as this is the "main" query loop and therefore query_posts() should be applicable...

Comment: Simple but important, did you flush your permalinks?

Comment: See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/250944/9579) for another possible solution for Numerical Pagination with custom queries using `WP_Query();`.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a secondary query or overwriting the main query inside a page template is the quickest and easiest way I know to break pagination.

The main query, which determines *which page to load* runs *before* your template thus the results on the page and the query that loads the page become out of sync. The main query does not know about your in-template modifications to the query. It doesn't matter that your in-template query modifies the "main" query. The changes come too late.

What you need to be doing is use a filter on `pre_get_posts`. Unless I am reading it wrong, all you need to do is set the `post_status`.

```
function set_post_type_for_archive_wpse_109213($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_archive()) {
    $post_type = $qry->get('post_type');
    if (empty($post_type)) {
      $post_type = array('post');
    }
    $post_type[] = 'review';
    $qry->set('post_type',  $post_type);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','set_post_type_for_archive_wpse_109213');
```

Unless you are the WordPress Core, and you aren't, `query_posts` is never applicable. Just don't use it.

Comment: Don't know why @21zna9 didn't accept this answer. This answer helped me. +1 for s_ha_dum