# Achieving pagination with `query_posts`

Tags: query-posts, pagination

I'm using `query_posts` to build a list of posts from a single category, and I'm trying to add pagination to this setup. Here's my code:

```
<ul>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'category' => 6, 'order' => 'DESC', 'paged' => 1 );
    $myposts = query_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li>
            <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
</ul>
<?php echo next_posts_link()?>
```

`<?php echo next_posts_link()?>` generates a "Next Page >>" link, which links to the current URL with `&paged=2` appended, but does nothing when clicked (no page loads occur whatsoever).

How can I get working pagination?

Comment: See:http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109234/21376

Comment: Additionally read Rarst's answer to [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/22534) and Stephen Harris' answer to [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/22534), because there almost never is a reason to use `query_posts` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'category'       => 6,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'paged'          => $paged,
);
```

Currently, you are setting The `paged` argument to `1`.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. Could it have something to do with how I'm getting the link to generate (using `<?php echo get_next_posts_link()?>`)?

EDIT: Using your solution, when I manually append `&paged=2` to the URL, it takes me to the second page, but the link (which is properly wrapped in an `<a>` tag), just doesn't work.

Comment: To clarify: hovering above the link makes my browser display the correct URL, with `&paged=2` included, in the little destination tooltip thing in the bottom left corner. Inspecting the code shows correct markup for a link leading to that page. Hovering above the link changes the cursor, but actually clicking the link has it acting as if I were clicking un-linked text.

Comment: Can you show the anchor `<a>` tag from the page source?

Comment: I prefer not to post the domain name, but the page is `http://mydomain.com/?page_id=600` and the `a href` attribute is `http://mydomain.com/?page_id=600&paged=2`

Comment: I suspect that a JavaScript script is changing the destination of the link. Is `href` the only attribute in the `<a>` tag?

Comment: Yes it is. I'll have a look at the scripts on the page tomorrow and update. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following expression to compute paged parameter for the query.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Instead of using query_posts i recommend you to use [pre_get_pots](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook

Visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query) for more information.

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't work, and I've tried both examples on the page you linked to (neither of which will take the category parameter, for some reason, and end up displaying nothing).

Comment: You have used query_posts along with foreach loop and setup_postdata() function instead you should use while loop the_post() function formmore information visit this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts