# Pagination Doesn't Work

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination, rewrite-rules, query-variable

**I created `myfile.php` with the following content:**

```
global $paged;
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
} else if ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('my_custom_post_type'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump($wp_query);
if($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        // show post
    endwhile;
endif;

next_posts_link('Next posts');

wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

and:

- when it's set to "Static Front Page" in Settings > Reading it works fine with pagination. I can access http://example.com/page/2
- when Settings > Permalinks is set to "Default Permalinks Structure" it works with http://example.com/?page_id=1234&paged=2
- when Settings > Permalinks is set to any "Custom Structure" the following http://example.com/mypage/page/2 launches 404.php.

I have no idea what am I missing here but I just tried every single suggestion from troubleshooting guide on this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination - they suggest that "404 - not found" is one of the common problems when the permalinks are set to "Custom Structure" so WP developers are aware of some bug or issue but they don't say how to fix that.

My server is WAMP for Windows 7 (PHP 5.4.3, Apache 2.4.2, `mod_rewrite` enabled, custom link structures work great expect pagination when "myfile.php" is used as a page other than "Static Front Page").

My .htaccess when "Custom Permalink Structure" is set to "Post name":

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I enter http://example.com/mypage/page/2 (doesn't work): `SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_name = 'page' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'my_custom_post_type' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC`

When I enter http://example.com/?page_id=1234&paged=2 (works): `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'my_custom_post_type' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 2, 2`

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)?

Comment: @toscho Yes, suggested answers contain the code that is almost the same like in my question.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109234/21376

Comment: @s_ha_dum It looks like what I need! However, I still have no idea how to enable pagination. When I do `$qry->set( 'paged', $paged );` in functions.php, entire /mypage/ page stops working.

Comment: Furthermore, I think that my main query which loads /mypage/ is alright. I'd like to list posts with pagination in a secondary loop on that page. Does your answer cover that situation too? It looks like it's for modifying the main query only.

Comment: See this then: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+paginate_links

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thank you for the link! I check all the answers and none worked so far. Every single answer that I found so far looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4795366/1074346 - it is a simple piece of code, upvoted and accepted answer but... it doesn't work because I get "404 - not found". My loop looks like this guy's loop and `next_posts_link()` returns the correct link but the link that is returned doesn't work with "Custom Permalink Structure". It is probably not even related to `$wp_query` and `$paged`. With "Default Permalink Structure" it works.

Comment: you've tried this with no plugins and with default theme active? your code works as-is for me.

Comment: @Milo That is correct. Unmodified Twenty Thirteen, 0 plugins activated, WordPress 3.6, WAMP on Windows 7. Pretty permalinks work except /page/2/ and /page/2/ also works if myfile.php is set to "Static Front Page".

Comment: have a look at the query it's sending to the database on the main query when it's returning a 404. I can't reproduce this, so not sure what the issue may be.

Comment: 404.php when I enter http://example.com/mypage/page/2 shows: `SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_name = 'page' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'my_custom_post_type' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC`

Comment: That's the unaltered main query? why is it trying to query your custom post type?

Comment: I don't know, the full code that I'm using is present in my question. This is the full content of myfile.php which is set to /mypage/ in Admin Panel > Pages > My Page. And to get this request I used `echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;` in 404.php.

Comment: If you're in 404.php, then your code isn't loaded on a 404, something else is setting that query to your custom type instead of a page. do you have any `pre_get_posts` stuff hooked anywhere?

Comment: `pre_get_posts` - no, nowhere. This is default WordPress theme in almost unmodified form. With default permalink structure this is the query in myfile.php: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'my_custom_post_type' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 2, 2` (just after `$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );`).

Comment: Just to clarify: the first query comes from myfile.php (and also 404.php) when I have "Custom Permalinks Structure" set to something that is not default. I'm absolutely sure that I don't modify `pre_get_posts` anywhere. I triple checked this. http://gyazo.com/7424251b5b9129ce83467334fbcc1dd8.png

Comment: @Paul If your question has been answered, could you please accept the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this with several plugins of my own, while trying to display a numerical pagination for my custom post types and custom taxonomies.

It's my understanding that by using [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to fetch posts from the database in your own custom way (other than the default) will prevent you from using such functions as expected.

They're intended to be used for the default posts query. So if you would like to use those functions as intended, then you'll need to modify the default query BEFORE the query is performed. You can do this using the hook `pre_get_posts`.

However, if you would like to use your own custom query using `WP_Query`, then you'll need to also customize how the numerical pagination works. You can get the same net result using standard WordPress functionality, but it requires a few extra lines of code to achieve the numerical pagination as expected.

**Let's say you have a custom query using `WP_Query` and it looks something like this:**

`$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );`

This means you have a completely BRAND NEW query which is *different* than the main default query which is performed when the page is loaded.

**Now WordPress is aware of TWO queries for the current page:**

1. **Query #1** being the *default query*.
2. **Query #2** being your *custom query* you just created using `WP_Query`.

If you want your numerical pagination to work with your custom query, then you need to be aware of the current page the request is performed on.

**The current page number is actually referred to as `paged`. You can determine the current page number using some code like this:**

```
$current_page = 1;

if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
}
```

**Once the current page has been determined, you can setup your custom query to look similar to this:**

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'products',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => absint( $current_page )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

**Once the query has been performed, you then need to check if it's located any posts in the database which match your criteria:**

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        // Post content here...

    }

} else {

    // No posts...

}
```

Now for the numerical pagination! I recommend using a WordPress function called [`paginate_links()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) for this part.

I don't really understand the really unlikely integer part for the `base`, but that's what's demonstrated on the WordPress Codex page linked above.

- You need to specify the current page (`paged`) -- once again.
- You need to know the total number of posts (which can be obtained
  from the `$query` variable object).
- You need to specify a return type for this function. (Personally, I
  like it to be in array format, so that I can customize the pagination
  however I see fit).

---

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

$previous_text = '&laquo; Previous';
$next_text     = 'Next &raquo;';

$pagination = paginate_links( array(
    'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format'    => '?current_page=%#%',
    'current'   => max( 1, $current_page ),
    'total'     => $query->max_num_pages,
    'type'      => 'array',
    'prev_text' => $previous_text,
    'next_text' => $next_text
) );
```

---

This code needs to be placed within the condition which states that we have posts available. Not inside the loop, but immediately AFTER the loop.

Once the numerical pagination has been configured, it's ready for output (or ready to be displayed). This is where paginated items are returned in `array` format.

I like to wrap it with a conditional check and then loop through the items performing additional conditional checks along the way.

```
if ( $pagination ) {

    $content .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>' . PHP_EOL;
    $content .= '<nav id="numerical-pagination" class="text-center">' . PHP_EOL;
    $content .= '<ul class="pagination">' . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ( $pagination as $pagination_item ) {

        $class = '';

        if ( stripos( $pagination_item, 'current' ) !== false ) {
            $class = ' class="active"';
        }

        if ( stripos( $pagination_item, 'dots' ) !== false ) {
            $class = ' class="disabled"';
        }

        $content .= '<li' . $class . '>' . $pagination_item . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;

    }

    $content .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
    $content .= '</nav><!-- end #numerical-pagination .text-center -->' . PHP_EOL;
    $content .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>' . PHP_EOL;

    echo $content;

}
```

**Note:** I use Bootstrap for my WordPress themes. So if you want your pagination to look awesome, with minimal effort involved. Try out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination).

To conclude everything mention above, here's a all-in-one copy/paste starter solution for anyone looking to create a numerical pagination with a custom posts query using `WP_Query`.

```
$current_page = 1;

if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
}

$query_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'products',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => absint( $current_page )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        // Post content here...

    }

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    $previous_text = '&laquo; Previous';
    $next_text     = 'Next &raquo;';

    $pagination = paginate_links( array(
        'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format'    => '?current_page=%#%',
        'current'   => max( 1, $current_page ),
        'total'     => $query->max_num_pages,
        'type'      => 'array',
        'prev_text' => $previous_text,
        'next_text' => $next_text
    ) );

    $content = '';

    if ( $pagination ) {

        $content .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>' . PHP_EOL;
        $content .= '<nav id="numerical-pagination" class="text-center">' . PHP_EOL;
        $content .= '<ul class="pagination">' . PHP_EOL;

        foreach ( $pagination as $pagination_item ) {

            $class = '';

            if ( stripos( $pagination_item, 'current' ) !== false ) {
                $class = ' class="active"';
            }

            if ( stripos( $pagination_item, 'dots' ) !== false ) {
                $class = ' class="disabled"';
            }

            $content .= '<li' . $class . '>' . $pagination_item . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;

        }

        $content .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;
        $content .= '</nav><!-- end #numerical-pagination .text-center -->' . PHP_EOL;
        $content .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>' . PHP_EOL;

        echo $content;

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

} else {
    // No posts...
}

wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below code.

```
function custom_type_archive_display($query) {

    if (is_post_type_archive('custom_post_type') )
    {
        $query->set('posts_per_page',10);
        return;
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_type_archive_display');
```

Answer (score -1):

After hours of struggling I found the cause.

The post type that I registered using `register_post_type( 'my_custom_post_type', array( ... ) );` had `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'my_custom_post_type' )`. That was taking priority over pagination and that's why "404 - not found" was happening.

If anyone has better explanation of what takes priority and when, please edit my answer. This issue is resolved after editing `rewrite` to something else.

Comment: Please accept your own answer

Comment: But you don't say what you changed it to that works!