# Pagination in custom loop for custom post type throwing 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, query, 404-error

I searched around for similar problems but it did not worked for me, im a total beginner with WordPress.

I made a custom query but the pagination throwing me 404 error

### Query

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$default = array(
    'post_type' => 'dlm_download',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => '_featured',
    'dlm_download_category' => $term->slug
);

$args = $default;

foreach ($downloads as $download) :  setup_postdata($download); 
// loop here
endforeach;
```

### Pagination

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                $big = 999999999; 
                $pagenum = str_replace( $big, '%#%',  get_pagenum_link( $big  ) );

                echo '<div class="pagination">';
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => $pagenum,
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
                    ) );
                echo "</div>";
```

And when i get `http://mysite.com/?dlm_download_category=kategoria-1&paged=2`

404 Error, could please someone give me a hint on this?

Comment: This question has been asked a lot lot lot of times. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops or http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109213/wordpress-custom-post-type-category-pagination-404-error/109234

Comment: As i highlighted, i searched, and it did not fix my problem, otherwise i would not asked

Comment: You are defining the arguments for the query in the `$default` variable but then pass an unknown `$args` variable to the `new WP_Query`, appart of that kind of PHP errors, your question is almost equal to a lot of questions asked before.

Comment: edited my question so you can see im passing correct data

Comment: Sorry @LeventeNagy but you are still using undefined variables, like `$downloads`, and your question is still almost equal to a lot of questions here in WPSE, like the questions linked in a previous comment.

Comment: Still thanks for your replies, actually it works now, i did way much more googling, and instead of paged, i had to use page, now its all fine. Still thanks for taking the time

Comment: See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/250944/9579) for another possible solution for Numerical Pagination with custom queries using `WP_Query();`.