# pre_get_posts Tax Query not working for custom author page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, author-template, tax-query

I am using the theme TwentyTwelve and modified the standard post query in the file author.php with the following code:

```
function wpd_author_query( $query ) {
//CODE to set $current_user_name here
//This gets the author from the URL
$author = get_user_by('slug',get_query_var('author_name'));
$current_user_name = $author->user_nicename;

    if ( $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query()) {
            // your code to set $current_user_name here
            $query->set( 'meta_key', '_writer_relation_added_date_'.$current_user_name );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
            $query->set( 'post_status', $post_status );

            $tax_query = array(  
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'writer',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'terms' => $current_user_name
                )
            );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }               
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_author_query' );
```

However, the tax_query is not working for the author page. It is still not retrieving the posts in the writer taxonomy.

I did try applying that code for other pages such as is_home() is_archive() and it does work.

So, there must be a conflict in with wordpress and the author template page that is not allowing me to use the tax_query for retrieving posts in the writer taxonomy.

Comment: Your query mentions nothing about the specifying the current author, therefore your results don't either

Comment: See Milo's answer. You are wrong when say ".... replaced the standard post query in the file author.php..." You have not replaced the query, you have made a new one.

Comment: @TomJNowell I did not post the code for retrieving the current author because it is not relevant.

Comment: @cybnet I did replace the code inside author.php with the one I posted.

Comment: That is why you are not replacing the main query, if you are in autor.php template file, the main query has been already executed. This has been asked a lot lot lot of times before. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109213/wordpress-custom-post-type-category-pagination-404-error/109234#answer-109234

Comment: @cybnet sorry to say you are wrong. You did not read my question. In my case, pagination was not working because the query was wrong! The query was not querying the correct posts, thus returning an empty result. It has now been fixed and posted the final solution with the help of Milo. I just had to unset the query var `author_name` as Milo indicated.

Comment: @Gixty I'm not wrong. If you are executing a query in a page template you CAN NOT replace the main query, NEVER, because the main has been already executed. If you don't want to accept it.....don't do it but it is actually an unquestionable fact. Read my comments and you noted that I've not said anything about your broken pagination but I've trying to correct some wrong concepts you have.

Comment: @cybnet ok, sorry for not understanding. So my wording is wrong. I said "replaced" because I removed the existing code and put my own. Again, sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Actually, this question **is a duplicate** of [How to fix pagination for custom loops](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops). The issue is the same, and the resolution is the same. The answer to the linked question also addresses the appropriate use of `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query.

Comment: "*However, the problem persists because after applying Milo's suggestion, the tax_query is not working for the author page. It is still not retrieving the posts in the writer taxonomy.*" - then you should **edit your question** to remove references to a secondary query, and include only your `pre_get_posts` callback. Then the question would no longer be duplicate, and would be a unique - *and useful * stand-alone question.

Comment: Please add your solution as an actual answer, and clarify the question so that the resemblance to the question marked as a duplicate is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't run a new query in the template, modify the main query *before* it's run via the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action in the theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function wpd_author_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_author()
        && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            // your code to set $current_user_name here
            $query->set( 'meta_key', '_writer_relation_added_date_' . $current_user_name );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
            $tax_query = array(  
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'writer',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'terms' => $current_user_name
                )
            )
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

            // EDIT
            // unset the requested author
            unset( $query->query_vars['author_name'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_author_query' );
```

You can then run the vanilla loop in the default author template, and save an extra query in the process.

Comment: I am still trying to get this to work. It is not retrieving the posts inside the `writer` taxonomy. I tried it in the home page with `is_home()` and it works, but it is not working in the author page.

Comment: it seems to work everywhere but in the author.php page. In the author page, it is retrieving only the posts made by the author and not querying the tax_query.

Comment: it's because the query has the author query var set based on the requested author. if you're using pretty permalinks, the query var is `author_name`. you can try to unset it so WordPress removes it from the query: `unset( $query->query_vars['author_name'] );`. see edit above.

Comment: Well, that did the trick; however, now I need to set back the query var again after altering the main query. How would I do this?

Comment: Thanks Milo! I figured it out and edited my question to add the solution. I could not have done it without your help. Where can I mark the question as NOT DUPLICATE?