# Pagination in custom loop

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I thought I know how to add pagination to a custom loop and I've seen these questions and tutorials:

- [Pagination not working with custom loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)
- http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/
- http://www.wplover.com/756/how-to-get-custom-wp_query-loop-working-with-pagination-and-wp-pagenavi/

but for some reason it doesn't work at this time. I created myfile.php, named it to "My Page Template" and set that to be my front page in Admin Panel > Settings > Reading.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('my_custom_post_type'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump($wp_query);
if($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        // show post
    endwhile;
endif;

next_posts_link('Next posts');

wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

What happens:

- Front page shows 3 posts as expected.
- "Next posts" link is shown and points to http://example.com/page/2/ as expected.
- While I'm on http://example.com/page/2/ it shows the same set of posts and "Next posts" link points to http://example.com/page/2/ which is not what I want.
- `var_dump($wp_query)` shows `public 'max_num_pages' => float 8`.
- `var_dump($wp_query)` shows `public 'found_posts' => string '24' (length=2)`.
- `var_dump($wp_query)` shows `public 'is_paged' => boolean false`.
- `var_dump($wp_query)` shows `'paged' => int 1` (when I'm on page number 2).
- When I'm renaming `$wp_query` to `$my_custom_query` then "Next posts" link doesn't show at all.

Is there anything else I should do here?

UPDATE:
I managed to set proper `$paged` by changing `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` to `$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;` but it still shows a wrong navigation link.

Comment: After you use the code in your update, before `next_posts_link` try: `global $paged; $paged = get_query_var('page');`.

Comment: @G.M. It still points to http://example.com/page/2/ when I'm on http://example.com/page/2/. `$paged` is `2`.

Comment: mmm, I've tested your code, exactly how you have posted, only implementing the change you pointed in your update (without using what I said in previous comment). It worked perfectly. So I think there is something else that cause the issue.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my loop is located in loop.php and I do `get_template_part()` i myfile.php. It seems not to pass variables there... Adding `global $paged;` before `$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;` and not only before `next_posts_link()` helped! Thank you for yor help! This is resolved!