# Pagination With Custom WP Query not functioning

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I have the following custom query and im attempting to paginate the links of previous archive posts using the example from the wordpress codex

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Basic_Example

Am i inserting this in the wrong place? I inserted before the end of the query with the basic arguments, and there is just a place space at the moment.

Any advice / tutorial is appreciated.

Update 2: Ive now tried the change in the wp_query in the pagination piece, and still no luck.

```
<div id = "innerpagemaincontent">
<h2 class="innerpagetitle">Latest News</h2>
    <div class="r-post clearfix">

 <?php // custom loop query
$carouselPosts = new WP_Query('showposts=5');

// Pagination fix
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $carouselPosts;

// open loop
if ( $carouselPosts ->have_posts() ) : while ( $carouselPosts->have_posts() ) :  $carouselPosts->the_post(); ?>

<div class="otherrecentpostswrap">
   <div id="postdetails"><div class="boldyfont">Posted by <?php the_author(); ?><br/><?php the_category(','); ?></div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_date (); ?></a></div>
    <div class="thumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(160,160)); ?><span class="overlay">    </span></a></div>

        <div id="postewrapper">
         <div class="recentpostscontent">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <span class="innerpageposttitle"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a class="readmorelink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read More </a>  </div></div>
<br/><br/>


</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php paginate_links(  array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $carouselPosts->max_num_pages
    ) ); ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: P.S. - [Pagination Not Working With Custom Loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop) *does apply*. That question and its answer are not specific to the WP PageNavi Plugin. The issue is the way that WordPress handles pagination when using a secondary loop. If the problem is that WordPress isn't recognizing that the loop is paginated, then the answer to that question *will* be a part of your ultimate solution here.

Comment: I tried the above and it didn't work thou :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 0):

One issue at least: you'll want to *close the loop* before outputting your pagination links, or else they'll be output on every iteration of the loop. But you've got `paginate_links()` *before* `endwhile;`.

Try this arrangement instead:

```
// open loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    // Loop markup

// close loop
endwhile; endif;

// pagination here
paginate_links( $args );
```

For a custom query loop, you'll want to handle the query accordingly:

```
// custom loop query
$custom = new WP_Query( $args );

// Pagination fix
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $custom;

// open loop
if ( $custom->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom->have_posts() ) : $custom->the_post();

    // Loop markup

// close loop
endwhile; endif;

// pagination here
paginate_links( $args );

// reset query
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: do i still need to add anything extra though chip to the functions? As obviously i went via the basic example on the codex

Comment: What kind of extra things? I think the first step is to make sure that your links are working properly; making `paginate_links()` work is its own beast. :)

Comment: so would it be best for me to just move the pagination after the end while... or will it still not work :S

Comment: Yeah, you want to add pagination *outside* the loop, but *inside* of your query manipulation/reset.

Comment: Hi Chip, please see update, would that work with my rewrite. I dont wanna do the php too open, i would rather do it closed per section so i can get my head round it

Comment: Does it work when you try it? :) You've got two competing issues here, so it's difficult to know which is the problem: custom-loop pagination, and proper output of `paginate_links()`.

Comment: lol ... i will try it... see what happens. I was assuming that my wp_query was ok (well it worked) and the pagination wasnt working ha!

Comment: nope... no links with that :(

Comment: Do the `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` tags work there?

Comment: http://www.naturallegacy.co.uk/beta/news/ this is the site, no links at all :(

Comment: How many posts are returned by your custom query? Enough to generate pagination of the archive index?

Comment: At chip yes, as I've only got 5 showing and there's 15 or so In the archive

Comment: Im unsure as to why this wouldnt work, as ive followed your answer, shall i post the code?

Comment: Might be good to try to pull this into chat at this point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11226/discussion-between-chip-bennett-and-kirsty-harris)

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and tried at my localhost. It was not working as `$wp_query->max_num_pages` is 0 but when i changed to `'total' => $carouselPosts->max_num_pages` it showing paging. I hope it will work in your system also. if it doesn't work, let me know, i will try to help again