# Pagination not working with custom post type

Tags: pagination

From [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4699/3206), I now have an adjusted WP_Query statement (I added the $paged variable):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'laptop', 'postsperpage' => '30', 'max_num_pages' => 20, 'paged' => $paged) );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) { ?>
   ...output content....
} ?>

<?php if ( $loop->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
<div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-previous">
    <?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'domain' ) ); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-next">
    <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'domain' ) ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; }
   wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Nothing is output in `<div class="nav-previous">` or `<div class="nav-next">`.

Can you see what is wrong here please?

Answer (score 2):

From [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link):

> Add the $max_pages parameter to the next_posts_link() function when
>   querying the loop with WP_Query. To get the total amount of pages you
>   can use the 'max_num_pages' property of the custom WP_Query object.

So:

```
next_posts_link( __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'domain' ), $loop->max_num_pages );
```

Comment: Thanks. After making the change above, I only receive a `← Previous` link, pointing to page 2, and no `Next` link...

Comment: Because you have put the word `previous` inside `next_posts_link`