# Pagination inside the blog page not working

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination, blog

I have a widget which creates a grid with pagination. If I am using the pagination then it works fine when used on the page to display grid.

But when I am using that in inside a blog post. The pagination is stuck at page 1 .

This is my arg used and I have used it inside the custom query loop.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
            $paged = apply_filters('pgggo_paginate_args_paged_hook', $paged);
            $args  = array(
                'format'    => 'page/%#%',
                'current'   => intval($paged),
                'total'     => intval($pgggo_query->max_num_pages),
                'mid_size'  => 2,
                'prev_text' => '<i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>',
                'next_text' => '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>',
            );
```

I have a few references but I am not how to use them to solve this issue.
[Pagination not working with custom loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)

Please help

Comment: Try `$paged = is_singular() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );`

Comment: @sally i was able to solve the problem by adding add_action on `+  $post_types = get_post_types($args, $output, $operator);
+ if ( is_singular( $post_types ) ) {
+   global $wp_query;
+   $page = ( int ) $wp_query->get( 'page' );
+   if ( $page > 1 ) {
+     // convert 'page' to 'paged'
+     $query->set( 'page', 1 );
+     $query->set( 'paged', $page );
+   }
+   // prevent redirect
+   remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
+ }
+}
+add_action( 'template_redirect', 'pgggo_fix_usage_single_posts',0 );`

Comment: Ok then. But perhaps you should post that code as an answer.